# Flutter/Dart global List variable changed in a foreach loop is unchanged after the loop

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, for-loop, foreach

I have a list declared outside a for loop and then I assign some values to this list inside that for loop and its value is updated when printed inside the loop but when I print it after the loop, it gives me an empty list.

```
  List<List<String>> chunkSizeCollection(List<String> followedList) {
    int counter = 0;
    int ongoingCounter = 0;
    bool isLessThanTen = false;
    List<List<String>> returnAbleChunkedList = [];
    List<String> midList = [];
    log("in followedlist");
    followedList.forEach((element) {
      if (counter == 0) {
        int difference = followedList.length - ongoingCounter;
        if (difference < 10) {
          // log("in difference if: $difference");
          isLessThanTen = true;
        }
      }
      midList.add(element);
      counter++;
      ongoingCounter++;
      if (counter == 10 || (isLessThanTen && ongoingCounter == followedList.length)) {
        returnAbleChunkedList.add(midList);
        log("returnAbleChunkedList in counter 10 after adding new val is: $returnAbleChunkedList");
        //above log works properly and prints the updated list
        midList.clear();
        counter = 0;
      }
    });
    //this log on the other hand, returns an empty list
    log("returnAbleChunkedList: $returnAbleChunkedList before return");
    return returnAbleChunkedList;
  }
```

The output:

```
[log] returnAbleChunkedList in counter 10 after adding new val is: [[KQTuEPllbmRrlBNvYgZ7oUXwtA63, OZUZOE10IzT8quUFoZbNxZOynU32, fCYIlYemCvbLTc7SpNHw6fCHrcm1, CbcLrtDNOdYZyC23FzEehOrJbKx2, FFvvVHCpPGNKUiXPQD34QdoPqH32, Gk09y59vSVXa1HNhzYvc6Atqnt53, JDO356z8urYQvuktJmc6eNUYqSm2, YesvvNI43gUVYPMfqhG4uRO5t6K2]]

[log] returnAbleChunkedList: [[]] before return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```dart
returnAbleChunkedList.add(midList);
midList.clear();
```

You add the object `midlist` to the list and then you clear it. So the object you added will be emptied. You have to create a copy or add the elements of the list.

```dart
returnAbleChunkedList.add(midList.toList());
// or
returnAbleChunkedList.add(List.of(midList));
// or
returnAbleChunkedList.add([...midList]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
      returnAbleChunkedList.add(midList);
```

you add a reference to `midList` to your output list. If your input is longer than 10, you'll end up adding more than one reference to `midList` to the output list (i.e. you might now have 2). Subsequently, you clear `midList` so you now have an output list that contains 2 references to a list that you've now cleared, so you end up with a list containing 2 empty lists.

If, instead, you changed this to:

```
      returnAbleChunkedList.add(midList.toList());
```

you'd add a copy of `midList` to your output list and your end up with:

```
[[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j], [k]]
```

as you expected.